# How to read KML file and show information on the screen android

Tags: android

I want to read a KML file that exists, and display information of it on the screen
this is the KML file that I have:

```
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
<Document>
 <gcname>ATM HCM</gcname>
  <Placemark>
    <name>MAC THI BUOI</name>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-81.4324182271957,43.5984273639879,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>TRUONG DINH</name>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-85.433182656765,41.5955730479591,0</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
```

anybody help me, pls!

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML parsing libraries. An example is on [this link](https://gist.github.com/RobGThai/3163006)

Another example from Android Developers page is [XMLPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)

Comment: i sry, but you can help me source code about this exercise, i realy need it now :(

Comment: I think you can handle it, i provided you examples. Just take a look at them and choose the simplest. Then start your fingers work ;)